# how to use tikz for uml diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

I'm new on latex and i need any documentation to guide me and help me know how to draw an uml diagram using tikz 
just got a book from previous answers but still dont get it
i tried an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{class}[text width=8cm]{className}{0,0}
        \attribute{name : attribute type}
        \attribute{name : attrribute type = default value}
        \operation{name(parameter list) : type of value returned}
        \operation[0]{name(parameters list) : type of value returned}
      \end{class}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Welcome! It is not very easy to help you with this, Obviously `class` is not an environment defined by `tikz` and/or `article`. So your code does not run through. The screen shot seems to be from a manual. I thought it could be `tikz-uml`, but adding `\usepackage{tikz-uml}` does not make your code working either (and to the best of my knowledge `tikz-uml` isn't an official package either). So please provide us with all the relevant information and make sure your code can be compiled.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you're using is from a package called `pgf-umlcd`. Hence, if you replace `\usepackage{tikz}` with `\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}` your example works fine. (Assuming the package is installed.)

`pgf-umlcd`, and its sibling package `pgf-umlsd`, are both on CTAN (the main repository for all things TeX) and in TeX Live and MikTeX. Their manuals can be found on http://texdoc.net/, on CTAN, or by entering e.g. `texdoc pgf-umlcd` in a terminal/command prompt on your computer (assuming the documentation was included when you installed TeX Live/MikTeX).

The `tikz-uml` package mentioned by Schrödinger's cat, is not on CTAN, but can be downloaded from the author's website (https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{class}[text width=8cm]{className}{0,0}
        \attribute{name : attribute type}
        \attribute{name : attrribute type = default value}
        \operation{name(parameter list) : type of value returned}
        \operation[0]{name(parameters list) : type of value returned}
      \end{class}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```